# Python import dynamically generated declarations

Tags: python

I have a class `Item` that declares various items for me to use in my programs. This class is instantiated on many occasions throughout the source code and each instance provides me with certain functionality. These instances are also stored in a global dict for easy retrieval by name as in

```
itm = get_item("name")
```

However, each program normally uses lots of these items, causing lots of these declarative lines. Additionally, the nature of these items is declarative more than instantiative so I figured a much nicer and proper way of "registering" these items would be to simply import them:

```
from item_storage import name1, name2, name3
```

Forget for a moment why I'd want to be doing this (let's just mention that these items are actually class declarations that can be dynamically extended, overridden and whatnot).

How can I trick Python (2.7) into allowing me to declare this `item_storage` module that would contain all the item definitions and still be good enough for import mechanism to work?

Comment: Are you looking for something else than writing `name1 = get_item("name1")` in `item_storage`? Please clarify.

Comment: item_storage is initially empty. Other files import it and execute `item_storage.name1 = get_item("name1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution I'm not particulary fond of: I have declared a custom import handler using `sys.meta_path`, so now `import item_storage` works from anywhere as soon as I import the relevant file for the first time.

However I was hoping for a technique less invasive (the handler gets invoked for each and every import).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand. But you could dynamically create the import line dynamically and then use exec to run it.

`exec "from item_storage import " + ", ".join(modules)`

Comment: why would this way be any different from just typing `from a import b`. At the time of use, b's are all known and not needed dynamically. I don't know, maybe this form would actually allow me to import?

Comment: this would allow you to import something which might not always be the same. if what is going to be imported can change you would need to do this

Comment: I have not tested whether this would actually work because this syntax breaks the fundamental requirement I need to satisfy: that objects actually get to be declared after the line so that PyDev doesn't report errors. Sorry for not mentioning this in the question.